# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR using NextAuth + Prisma in localhost

Tags: ssl, next.js, prisma, next-auth, next.js13

I have a Next.js 13 app with a MySQL database and I am adding authentication via NextAuth. I am using the prisma adapter to use it as my ORM.

I have configured all as it is detailed in the guide (https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/prisma).

When I click the "Sign in with Credentials" button from the default NextAuth page I am redirected to "https://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/credentials" but it shows this error `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` `This Site Can’t Provide a Secure Connection`.

The same happens when I click "Sign Out" in the signout page.

I tried disabling certificate verification with the env variable `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` I have seen in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58003959/11909334 .

Also tried to ignore the SSL error in chrome: "Since you are running your application on localhost for development purposes, you can simply ignore the SSL error. Most modern browsers provide an option to proceed despite the error. For example, in Chrome, you can click on "Advanced" and then select "Proceed to localhost (unsafe)"."

Also tried this solution https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/19400#discussion-5225423 .

And tried other browsers like Microsoft Edge.

I found this person having the same error https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/19494#discussion-5243149

Comment: r u using google provider?

Comment: @Yilmaz by this time i am only using credentials provider

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found the error after a lot of hours of searching... I had my NEXTAUTH_URL defined as `https://localhost:3000` with HTTPS instead of HTTP.

The solution consists only in replacing `https://localhost:3000` with `http://localhost:3000` in the .env file.

Answer (score 2):

Removing `VERCEL="1"` from  my `.env` fixed this for me. Vercel had automatically added it when setting up their postgres solution.

Comment: That solved my problem, thanks.